# Use of \GetIdInfoAuxI doesn't match its definition and other errors

Tags: incompatibility, mdframed, nag

I have several errors reported with this minimal example (latest TeX Live 2012).
The errors were introduced with recent TeX Live updates.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RequirePackage{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In `xparse.sty`:

> ! Use of `\GetIdInfoAuxI` doesn't match its definition.
>   l.66 `\GetIdInfo$
>                   Id: xparse.dtx 4467 2013-03-12 08:29:05Z joseph $`

In `etoolbox.sty`:

> (`c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty`
>   ! Missing `$` inserted.

In `mdframed.sty`:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry `[input stack size=5000]`.
>   `\etoolbox.sty-h@@k ->\etoolbox.sty-h@@k 
>                                           \etb@catcodes \undef \etb@catcodes` 
>   l.72 `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}`[2011/01/03]

Comment: I'd love to drop the entire `\GetIdInfo` business: a team decision, though, so not mine :-(

Comment: Why do you want to load `mdframed` at this point? I don't know any conflicts with other packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by @DavidCarlisle details the cause of this problem, and while the solution works it may be preferrable to use a solution with less catcode magic. Using the `\AtEndPreamble` macro provided by `etoolbox`, one can rewrite the MWE so that no errors occur:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{morewrites}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \RequirePackage{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Although I see no reason to postpone loading `mdframed` to begin with.

Comment: +1 see: you've more points than my answer already;-)

Answer (score 5):

The nag package changes `$` from its usual definition to be "active"

```
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`$\active}%$
\AtEndDocument{\catcode`$=3\relax}
```

It tries to minimise the clashes that this can cause by delaying it to begin document.

the mdframed (via xparse) use `$` to parse the source control headers in the package files
This fails as the `RequirePackage` has been delayed until BeginDocument.

The most obvious fix for this is just to use

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
```

rather than

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RequirePackage{mdframed}
}
```

But it depends why the package loading was delayed in the first place...

---

As noted in comments delaying package loading in `\AtBeginDocument` is always risky as it loads the package later than intended, after LaTeX has set up global font and page size structures, however this works:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}

    \documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage{morewrites}
    \RequirePackage{listings}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \edef\saveddcatcode{\the\catcode\expandafter`\string$}%
      \catcode`\$3 %
      \RequirePackage{mdframed}%
        \catcode`\$ \saveddcatcode\relax
    }

    \begin{document}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: In my packages I try to move package loading to the end to avoid option clashes.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech It's relatively fragile thing to do, apart from clashing with other packages (nag here) trying to do use the same hook to avoid clashes, any packages that load fonts or change any page layout size or ... should be loaded _before_ this hook is run as latex sets up its output routine and global font tables before executing code from AtBeginDocument. mdframed is probably safe normally but....

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech workaround code added to answer.

Comment: Perhaps using `\AfterEndPreamble` from the `etoolbox` package instead of `\AtBeginDocument` is a cleaner solution?

Comment: @You if you tested that and it works you should post as a separate answer, you might steal a few points from me:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Good idea :). Turns out `\AtEndPreamble` works better than `\AfterEndPreamble`.